# How do I plot a plane AND a graph in ONE 3D Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to plot the Van der Waals-equations, specifically the part in which the Van der Waals loop is shown. First I tried plotting it with the `Plot3D[]` function, tho the upper edges are very uneven and even with `MaxRecursion` set to 15 I couldn't get rid of the problem.

```
R=8.314;
a=363.7*10^-3;
b=42.7*10^-6;
Plot3D[p, {V, 0, 0.001}, {T, 290, 320}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotRange -> {0, 12000000}, AxesLabel -> {"V", "T", "p"}, 
 ImageSize -> 1100, Exclusions -> {V == 0, T == 0}, MaxRecursion -> 8,
  ViewPoint -> {0, -\[Infinity], 0}, ColorFunction -> Green]
```

When I used the `ContourPlot3D[]`, I didn't had that problem.

```
ContourPlot3D[(R T)/(V - b) - a/V^2 == p, {V, 0, 0.001}, {T, 280, 
  340}, {p, 0, 12000000}, AxesLabel -> {"V", "T", "p"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 0.8]
```

Now I want to have a graph which a specific value for T (such graphs are called isotherms), which is plotted in the same `ContourPlot3D`. Also, I want to create a slider, in which I specify the value for T.
I do know, that the `Show[]` function can be used, but don't know how to use it in this scenario since I want to plot two different things (a plane and graph) in one 3D plot.

Is there a way to to that? If yes, I'd be very thankful for your help :)

---

Thank you kglr!
Tho does anyone understand why these uneven edges occur when using the Plot3D function and why there's a hole in the function plotted using ContourPlot3D?

[image: uneven edges of a function plotted with Plot3D]

[image: Hole in plotted function using ContourPlot3D]

Comment: the values for `R`,`a` and `b`?

Comment: You can take a look at [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine the plots and at [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) for the slider.

Comment: @kglr, R=8.31 :)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry! 
R=8.314
a=363.7*10^(-3)
b=42.7*108^(-6)

Comment: thank you Henri and @Rom38.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  Show[ContourPlot3D[(R T)/(V - b) - a/V^2 == p, 
   {V, 0, 0.001}, {T,  280, 340}, {p, 0, 12000000}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"V", "T", "p"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, # &, #3 &}, 
    Mesh -> {{m}, 20, 20}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Automatic, Automatic}], 
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Blue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{0, m, 0}, {1, m, 0}, {1, m, 1}}]}]], 
 {m, 280, 340}]
```

[image]